# Access to XMLHttpRequest at URL has been blocked by CORS POLICY in AMPLIFY

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, aws-amplify

I am trying to use amplify storage - AWS S3 in one of our react application but getting error while doing putObject.

```
const user = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
      console.log("user:", user);
      const uploadResult = await Storage.put("test.txt", "Hello");//throwing error
      console.log("Upload result : ", uploadResult);
```

Error:
**Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://xxxxxx.amazonaws.com/public/test.txt?x-id=PutObject' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.**

Here is my CORS configuration of S3. I have allowed all origins and headers for testing but still getting error.

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET",
            "HEAD",
            "PUT",
            "POST",
            "DELETE"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": [
            "x-amz-server-side-encryption",
            "x-amz-request-id",
            "x-amz-id-2",
            "ETag"
        ],
        "MaxAgeSeconds": 3000
    }
]
```

Please help me out in this.

Comment: Do you have `public` directory created in S3 bucket you are uploading the file to ?

Comment: @sakhunzai, No, is that needed? Also I want user to upload file only if Authenticated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue might be that the `public` directory to which you are uploading the file might not exists in bucket. You have two options ,either create a public directory in bucket or don't upload to public directory.

```
await Storage.put(s3_object_key, file|content,{
    customPrefix: {public:''}
});
```

In your case

```
const uploadResult = await Storage.put("test.txt", "Hello",{customPrefix:{public:''}});
```

[Also remember](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/storage/configureaccess/q/platform/js#customization) , if you dont upload to public directory you might have to update IAM policies generated by amplify, therefore check s3 bucket and create public directory if its not there already.

To restrict only authenticated user, you use different strategy. Amplify attaches several IAM policies to s3 bucket it and it depends on how that is setup when you run `amplify add|update storage`. Please check different [file access levels](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/storage/configureaccess/q/platform/js).